# convert https non www domain to https www

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to automatically redirect from `example.com` to `www.example.com`.

Here is my wordpress htaccess code.....

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com//$1 [R,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

From now on, when someone accesses https://yourdomain.com s/he will be redirected to https://www.yourdomain.com.

Answer (score 0):

To convert

- https://example.con (ssl non-www)

to

- https://www.example.con (ssl www)

you can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Just change **R** to **R=301** when you are sure the Rule is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful to you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It will add www automatically in your domain.

for eg:  https://fastassignmenthelp.co.uk/ to     https://www.fastassignmenthelp.co.uk/